# SQLLDR -- selective loading from pipe delimited txt

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am looking for a way to do selective loading using SQLLDR. 
The source file is in "pipe delimited" format.

I know there is a way for this if the source is in a predefined position. It is explained [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ#Can_one_selectively_load_only_the_records_that_one_needs.3F), by using WHEN & POSITION keywords.

What could I do if the source file is "pipe or tab" delimited?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean with "selective loading"?

But ify you are only asking how you can load a file where each column is delimited with a pipe, then use the option `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'` in the control file.

See the chapter "Variable Record Format" in the SQL*Loader manual for more details and examples:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm#sthref476

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of the SQLLDR version you are using, you can use the keyword FILLER to skip a field from the file.

The below instruction will skip the second field in the file.

```
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE T1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
( field1,
  field2 FILLER,
  field3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'c:\myfile.txt'  
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE T1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS (field1, field2 , field3, field4)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.